# Can a dropdown and ajax work together? What if the dropdowns are connected directly into database via back end?

Tags: ajax

I'm currently working on my dropdowns and Ajax. Based on my understanding ajax is used to create graphs. But the thing is, I don't know if Ajax charts and dropdowns can work together. Another problem is that my dropdowns are connected directly to the database via back coding. I'm curious if a dropdown that's connected directly to the database can work together with Ajax so that I can manipulate and filter the charts and graphs. And if it is possible, what are the syntaxes that I can use to do that?

Sorry, I only have a month of real experience in programming so I'm having troubles on explaining my questions.

I tried what I see on the chatgtp but still I can't figure it out. Additionally, I'm currently using asp.net on my program so I don't know what to do.

Comment: With and based on ajax call and data returned you can manipulate the data inside any HTML element, so the answer is yes, could you provide us with code of what you're trying to do ?